# Wordpress custom post type change permalink query

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

My permalink rules are set to post name. I created a custom post type named: house.
The default url would be: `{{site_url}}/house/{{house_slug}}`
Now I want to change the way the house url is used, I want it to accept the following:
`/house/param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3`

I would like it that the query object used in the `pre_get_posts` method contains the post type (house) and the sent parameters.

I tried the following rewrite rules 1 by 1 but couldn't get a single one working:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^house/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'house/$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^house/(.*)[/]?$', 'house?test=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^house/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=house&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Comment: You would probably get better answers on [wordpress.se] than here.

Answer (score 0):

If you will accept anything after /house you can use: `/([^/]+)/`. So your last one should be it: `add_rewrite_rule( 'house/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=house&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );`

It's important to flush the rewrite rules by re-saving the permalinks in WordPress: settings -> permalinks -> save.

That should do the trick.

You can check this by exporting your rules (in functions.php):

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'debug_404_rewrite_dump' );
    function debug_404_rewrite_dump( &$wp ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        echo '<h2>rewrite rules</h2>';
        echo var_export( $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules(), true );
}
```

Comment: When I use that it will still show as: `[attachment] => params2:value2` instead of having both parameter 1 & 2 and the wp_query does not contain the post type to recognize the current post type